# vba select unixtimestamp from specific column and convert to date and time

Tags: vba, converters, unix-timestamp

i have an Excel file which has a lot of unix timestamps in column "C" for example (1422885360). I need a vba script which converts this unix timestamp to date (dd.mm.yyyy) and time (mm:hh:ss). The date and time should be in the same column, so the unix timestamp from column "C" should be overwritten.

Who can help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: i was looking for codes on google, but i didn't found any code which helped, and each of them which I found was very different, so thats why i posted no code.

Comment: You probably need a UDF but, without an algorithim to start with, it's impossible to answer your question. As @sildoreth commented, show some code.

Comment: i think its useless, that I will give you a code, which is completely not working for me, but here you have any which i found in google

Comment: Public Function VB_CTime(ByVal dblSec As Double) As Variant
    Dim vStart As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    vStart = DateSerial(1970, 1, 1)
    VB_CTime = DateAdd("s", dblSec, vStart)
    ' Anpassung auf Zeitzone
    VB_CTime = DateAdd("h", 1, VB_CTime)
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Function

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating solution attempts usually get downvoted and closed. P.S. Some random code copied from some search hit does not count as an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code (formula) I solved it, to convert a unix timecode to a date and time.

Just for information, my unix timecode was in column C and I added a formula in column D, in which the date and time should be seeable.

```
lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this counts until the last entry of the column C
Range("D2").Formula = "=(C2/86400)+25569+(+1/24)" 'this is the formula to convert the unix time code to date and time. The +1 is for the timezone, so i live in Austria which has a timezone GMT+1
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow) 'this copies the formula to column D to the same amount of rows of column C
Range("D2:D99999").NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS" 'this changes the cell format to a custom format
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix epoch timestamp is just the number of seconds from Jan 1st 1970

```
Range("C1").Value = DateAdd("s", Range("C1").Value, "1/1/1970")
```

Loop as appropriate for your range.

Comment: thanks david, but its not working well, because it coverts each unixtimestamp to one and the same date and time. Here you can find my file [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rvw41vzgxuzakt/File.csv?dl=0)